# Duplicate text from one textarea to another (hidden)

Tags: input, textarea

I have two input textareas, and the second one is hidden. Is it possible to automatically duplicate text typed in the first textarea to to the second?

So far I can think of 1) javascript, but not sure how to implement that. 2) do something with my forms in php:

```
$form['textarea1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => 'title',
  '#rows' => 20,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

and

```
$form['textarea2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#rows' => 20,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => value from textarea 1?
);
```

btw, it's Drupal.

Thank you for any suggestions.

**Update**. The first form is being built by special module and it saves the data to it's own table instead of saving data to drupal system table (node_revisions). My module creates the second form to duplicate data to drupal system table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('#textarea1').keyup(function() {
    $('#textarea2').val( $('#textarea1').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function postChange (psCopyFromId, psCopyToId)
{
   var copyFrom = document.getElementById(psCopyFromId);
   var copyTo = document.getElementById(psCopyToId);



   copyTo.value = copyFrom.value;
}



<textArea id="txt1" onChange="postChange(this.id, 'txt2');"></textArea>
<textArea id="txt2"></textArea>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I just wanted to let you know your answer solved my problem (I'm using an older non-jQuery version of a CMS for work). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can do it with javascript

But why do you want to have two textfields with the same content... I am assuming that you are submitting a form? Can't you just post the content from one place and then when you capture the results use the same Request.Form(content) for both values?

Comment: Gerald, I answered your question above =)